# How to retain values of array inside async loop? javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I have code below that uses api to fetch customer data. Problem is when it the loop went to the second index, the `customerIds` does retain the value from the previous `index` (see console log below).

Somebody knows how to achieve this properly?

---

Here is my code

```
let customerIds = [];

arrayChunks.forEach(async (chunkGroupIds, index) => {
    try {
        console.log('customerIds - before', index, customerIds)

        const checkStatusResult = await checkStatus(
            token,
            chunkGroupIds
        )

        chunkGroupIds.map((customerId) => {
            const found = checkStatusResult.response.data.find(
                (data) => customerId.toString() === data.customerId
            )

            if (found) {
                customerIds = [...customerIds, customerId]
            }
        })
        
        console.log('customerIds - after', index, customerIds)
    } catch (error) {
        ...
    }
})

console.log('customerIds - final', customerIds)
```

**Console logs:** The problem can be shown by the text being printed. As we can see when it went to second index it did not get the previous value from index one.

```
customerIds - before 0 []
customerIds - after 0 [2,3,5]
customerIds - before 1 []
customerIds - after 1 []
... and so on

customerIds - final []
```

Comment: @appleapple i originally used `push` but it did not worked.

Comment: `customerIds` should be correct after the loop. (you need to wait for it to complete though)

Comment: where is `customerIds` declared?

Comment: yes I originally think you cache the `customerIds`, re-read it and it's not the case. (so I delete the comment for use `push`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `for of` loop instead of the callback approach

```js
let customerIds = [];
let index = 0;

for (const chunkGroupIds of arrayChunks) {
    try {
        console.log('customerIds - before', index, customerIds)

        const checkStatusResult = await checkStatus(
            token,
            chunkGroupIds
        )

        chunkGroupIds.map((customerId) => {
            const found = checkStatusResult.response.data.find(
                (data) => customerId.toString() === data.customerId
            )

            if (found) {
                customerIds.push(customerId);
            }
        })
        
        console.log('customerIds - after', index, customerIds)
    } catch (error) {
        ...
    } finally {
       index++;
    }
}

console.log('customerIds - final', customerIds)
```

Comment: it now displaying the correct values.. i think its working. Do you have idea why my code above did not worked. or maybe is this because, there is `async` within `forEach` function that I used. However if I remove `async` I'll got typescript error.

Comment: Yes, previous one didn't work because of the callback implementation. `For each` method returns a callback for each array element iteration, and each callback has it's own execution context, you cannot use `async await` to wait for first iteration to complete if you have `async` code inside the callback. Each iteration runs independently of the other.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an asynchronism problem, it might seem as the promises in the array run sequentially, but they are not. In the `forEach` loop all of them are running simultaneously.

This might be something good in your case since you don't have to wait for the sum of the sequential time, where you probably are struggling is in the final part where you want to see the final array with all the appended values, for this I recommend the following:

```js
const promises = arrayChunks.map(async (chunkGroupIds, index) => {
    try {
        console.log('customerIds - before', index, customerIds)

        const checkStatusResult = await checkStatus(
            token,
            chunkGroupIds
        )

        chunkGroupIds.map((customerId) => {
            const found = checkStatusResult.response.data.find(
                (data) => customerId.toString() === data.customerId
            )

            if (found) {
                customerIds = [...customerIds, customerId]
            }
        })
        
        console.log('customerIds - after', index, customerIds)
    } catch (error) {
        ...
    }
})

await Promise.all(promises); // Wait until all of them are finished
console.log('customerIds - final', customerIds)
```

Here the `Promise.all` utility allows you to wait until a collection of promises is finished, the functions are automatically mapped to a promise thanks to the `async` keyword.

In case you need your promises to be executed sequentially, you can use the approach recommended by @amir-saleem. Otherwise, my suggestion would be better in terms of performance.

Comment: i got typescript error *No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(values: readonly unknown[] | []): Promise<[] | unknown[]>', gave the following error.*

Comment: That error doesn't seem related to the code you posted originally, can you provide more context?